# SQL to return all students with minimum GPA

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to do a query which, as the title says, returns the name of all the students that share the minimum GPA.

Since the minimum GPA from all the students I have in the table is 0, right now I have:

```
Select s.name from Student s
where s.gpa = 0
```

However, I don't want to put the value '0' since it could not always be the case, instead I'm trying to find the minimum gpa with `MIN(gpa)`

I've been trying to use that aggregate function in combination with `group by` But I cannot make it work. So far I have this:

```
Select s.name from Student s
having s.gpa = min(s.gpa)
group by s.gpa
```

How should I change it to make it work? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first find what is the minimum GPA, then get students that have it.

To get the minimum GPA in the entire table:

```
SELECT MIN(gpa) FROM Student;
```

This query can be nested inside your original query:

```
SELECT name FROM Student
WHERE gpa = (SELECT MIN(gpa) FROM Student);
```

I am not sure if there is a simpler way to do it. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! I was trying to do something similar as well but I didn't know how to implement the nested queries